# Hyperledger Fabric error: signature set did not satisfy policy

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

I've created a network configuration with 2 orgs, each one with 1 peer and CA.
I've successfully installed and instantiated my chaincode on both peers
But after invoking a transaction this error occurs on both peers:

```
peer0.org1.example.com|2020-01-27 21:32:00.531 UTC [committer.txvalidator] validateTx -> ERRO 047 VSCCValidateTx for transaction txId = d18ad9c8c5e6aada47b7c8677676b4d748bf2ae16256c093ae8f9dfb0bf17779 returned error: VSCC error: endorsement policy failure, err: signature set did not satisfy policy
peer0.org2.example.com|2020-01-27 21:32:00.531 UTC [committer.txvalidator] validateTx -> ERRO 069 VSCCValidateTx for transaction txId = d18ad9c8c5e6aada47b7c8677676b4d748bf2ae16256c093ae8f9dfb0bf17779 returned error: VSCC error: endorsement policy failure, err: signature set did not satisfy policy
```

that's how I installed the chaincode on both peers:

```
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -l node -p /opt/gopath/src/github.com/mychaincodes/
```

that's how I instantiated my contract

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/cacerts/ca.example.com-cert.pem -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -l node -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":[]}' -P "AND ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')"
```

and that's how I invoked transaction

```
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/ca/ca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n mycc --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem -c '{"Args":["createMyAsset","001","Model X"]}'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During chaincode instantiation, you specify the endorsement policy for this chaincode as `"AND ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')"`, which means that peers from both organisations have to endorse the transaction.

Then you only connect to `peer0.org1.example.com:7051` during chaincode invocation.

To make this work, you have to either change the endorsement policy to `"OR ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')"`, or connect to peers in both orgs while invoking chaincode, by adding another `--peerAddresses ...` entry.